# Is there a way to improve query time across relations?

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

Is there a way to improve query time across relations? Yet to measure, but I'm currently modeling my data in Memgraph in such a way that I will have several versions, and a typical query will look like:

```
MATCH (:Version { major: $major, minor: $minor })--(t:Thing { name: $name })
```

Of course, I can create an index over major/minor and over the name, but I worry that given nearly all queries will actually look for a composite index + relation it'll still have some performance impact.
I will need to measure this, but wanted to see whether someone has some insight for me already, and if there is something I can do to improve this. Also, there are < 100 of `:Version` and > 100000 of `:Thing`, so essentially the degree of `:Version` will be very high)
Wondering if I should convert this to be a single field on `:Thing`, for better indexing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring, I would say that the current model looks fine. It would be good to have an index on the name of the `:Thing` nodes, for sure, creating it on `:Version` is questionable and should be measured.
Use `EXPLAIN/PROFILE` query to see different options and test the performance
But I think

`MATCH (t:Thing {name : $name})--(:Version {major: $major, minor: $minor})`

with index on `Thing(name)` should be enough.
I did reverse the order but it shouldn't matter actually.